# Software to manage artifacts for various product releases?

Tags: file-management

Can anyone suggest a good software to manage the released artifacts for various different products?

Our firm has various products, for which releases happen now and then. We use a collaboration application (not very good in showing search results), to log the latest product release information (version, where to find the artifacts) in each product's space. However, it doesn't capture the previous releases (features released, previous versions, software location etc). All the release artifacts live in a shared folder on a different machine. Its been very difficult to find the required product version, by looking at the product page and shared location.

I wonder if there is any application which could Log the releases for each product, its features and store the released software for internal (not customers) usage?

Comment: Self-hosted/internally hosted version control system .... it doesn't have to be JUST source code. Binaries, shared libs, images, documentation, other multimedia assets, etc.